# Script doesn't remember root password

Tags: passwords, sudo

I created a script (I'm running it as root) that builds and installs some packages what takes some time, so around third package I had to re-enter root password.

I added while :; do sudo -v; sleep 60; done & at the start of the script, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can't you just `su` to go into sudo mode, and run the script? that should not have a timelimit. you can type `exit` to go back to normal mode.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking about. We need more details. If you run the script as `root` it will be executing with the root privileges all the time unless the script (or other part launched from it) changes to a different user at some point.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the sudo password is cached for 5 minutes. You can extend this by changing the timeout length:
Run: `sudo visudo`. In the file, you'll want to add at the end:
`Defaults:USER timestamp_timeout=30`
where USER is the username in question.

Taken from https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-change-the-default-sudo-timeout/

Comment: I want to know why `sudo -v` command doesn't work, not how to do it in other way.